# Convert time series into Bezier-smoothed chart, output chart bitmap to 2D array

Tags: c#, system.drawing, smoothing

I'm trying to Bezier-smooth a time series and convert it into a greyscale bitmap of its chart. To clarify, I essentially want C# to take a time series of data, virtually plot a smoothed chart a la Excel, convert this chart into a greyscale bitmap, and output the 2D numeric array of pixel values.

GDI+'s DrawBezier function seems to only directly create a visual display as output. If I redirect its output to an Image object, I think I can convert that into a pixel value array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use Bezier?  I can't imagine how you would use Bezier curves to approximate data.  Perhaps you want [Polynomial Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)?
As for drawing the cart, perhaps you should look into one of the many free charting libraries for .NET, like this one http://www.ujihara.jp/jbyjsharp/jfreechart/ (have not tried myself).

Comment: I'd planned on a Bezier curve because I wanted to mimic Excel's smoothing function, but polynomial interpolation works just as well. Do you know of a charting library which can output to a bitmap object?

Comment: I'm sure they all can do it.  What else could be the output of a charting library?  This one explicitly promises that http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/